# Printing using ArcGIS runtime Java

Tags: printing, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I have a map viewer that was developed using the ArcGIS Runtime Java SDK. I am trying to make a print button and it works with one issue. I can't seem to figure out how to make it fit on one page.

```
    private void printMap() {

    Paper paper = new Paper();

    // ...set up the paper options...
    PrinterJob printJob1 = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob(); 
    PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
    HashPrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();  


      if (printJob1.printDialog(set)) {
            try {printJob1.print(set);}
            catch (PrinterException exc) {
               // System.out.println(exc);
             }
         }  

     //set up page format [DEFAULT] options and pass the paper settings through
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    // set page format for the map to print
    map.setPageFormat(pageFormat);
    printJob1.setPageable(map);

    try {
       // send job to printer!
       printJob1.print();

       // new PrintMe().print(YourJTextComponent);

    } catch (PrinterException e) {
       // handle the exception
    }

}
```

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR1, resolution is 1920x1080. Any ideas or suggestions?

This is how it prints [image]

Answer (score 1):

got it. What I did was convert the map into a png and then printed it.

I used [this](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/93537-Exporting-map-to-a-pdf-or-Iimage?p=353591&viewfull=1#post353591) as a reference to convert the map into a image.